# how to get the row difference within same group with different value in certain col

Tags: r

I have a df like below and would like to calculate the fee difference for each ID:

1. df %>% arrange (ID, Date) %>% group_by (ID);
2. `Diff= Fee-lag(Fee)` when `Test != lag(Test)`
3. if Test== lag(Test), then Diff equal to Fee- Fee from the most closest different Test

The outputs will looks like the one on the right. I am not sure how to get the orange part done.  Could anyone guide me on this? Thanks.

[image]

```
df<- structure(list(ID = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Jerry", "Jerry", 
"Jerry", "Jerry"), Date = c(20220901, 20220902, 20220903, 20220904, 
20220905, 20220906, 20220907, 20220908), Test = c("ELA", "Art", 
"ELA", "ELA", "Art", "ELA", "ELA", "Math"), Fee = c(78, 98, 66, 
85, 78, 58, 96, 88)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the expected, we get the difference between the 'Fee' grouped by 'ID' and then get the `diff`erence of the `abs`olute in 'Diff' after adding `rleid` on 'Test' as grouping when there are more than 1 element per group

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Fee - lag(Fee)) %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(Test), .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = if(n() > 1) c(first(Diff), diff(abs(Diff))) else Diff) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  ID        Date Test    Fee  Diff
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tom   20220901 ELA      78    NA
2 Tom   20220902 Art      98    20
3 Tom   20220903 ELA      66   -32
4 Tom   20220904 ELA      85   -13
5 Jerry 20220905 Art      78    NA
6 Jerry 20220906 ELA      58   -20
7 Jerry 20220907 ELA      96    18
8 Jerry 20220908 Math     88    -8
```

Comment: The output is what I want! Could you explain more on `group_by(Test, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = if(n() > 1) c(first(Diff), diff(abs(Diff))) else Diff) ` part? Thanks.

Comment: @Stataq The `Diff` is created by taking the difference between the adjacent elements after grouping by 'ID', then inorder to consider the 'Test' groups, added another grouping with Test' and get the absolute difference between the adjacent elements of 'Diff' calculated only when number of elements in groups `n()` is greater than 1.  `diff` returns length 1 one less than the original group length.  thus, we concatenate the first element with the difference

Comment: It looks like `c(first(Diff), diff(abs(Diff)))` get the sum of two?  Sorry for sounding silly. Where can I find the reference for this?

Comment: @Stataq The reason is that one of the value is already negative.  So, if you do `diff(Diff)`, it will add, so I used `abs`olute

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clearer.  will `c(x, y)=x+y`? I thought c(x, y) just listing x and y.

Comment: what if we changed Tom's Math to ELA? the ideal output should stay the same. what should I do for that case? I updated sample data code in the question accordingly.

Comment: @Stataq `c` is for concatenation i.e. `diff` returns length one less than the original length, so I concatenated the first element with`c`

Comment: @Stataq With your new data, I think we need `rleid` (updated the answer)